Supply weights/number of obs to instead of one obs per row when doing multinomial regression?
EDIT: The code below is using statsmodels but I have the same problem when using sklearn.
I'm trying to do multinomial regression using the statsmodels MNLogit package. It says in the documentation that each row in X and Y is one observation. I mean that as one row is on combination of the x:s and y, where y:s output is one of three categories. If there are more then one observation of the combination of x:s and y, that means several identical rows. I would much rather supply any combination of x:s and y only once and also supply the number of observations some times called weights, as it's own column. It seems possible in other statistical packages but I havn't found out how to do it in this one.
The reason why I want to do this is of I have million of observations the calculation becomes very slow or not possible. If I express the data with number of observations as a column, that dataframe could be just a few hundred rows becouse all my x:s are categorical values with only a few categories.
Can I do this with MNLogit or do you have any tips of another package which performs multinomial regression? Here is a toy example of a dataset with different number of repetitions of observations. The coefficients stay same as long as the ratio amoung the number of observation is the same, but the p-values differ.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import sys
import os

def train_with_different_no_rows(n_mult):
    df = generate_data()
    df = repeate_lines_of_data(df, n_mult)
    return train_model(df)

def generate_data():
    np.random.seed(42)
    n_obs = 100
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'X1': np.random.rand(n_obs),
        'X2': np.random.rand(n_obs)
    })
    def generate_y(x1, x2):
        z = -2 * x2 + np.random.randn(len(x1)) * 0.1
        y = np.digitize(z, bins=[-0.5,0, 0.5])
        return y
    df['Y'] = generate_y(df['X1'], df['X2'])
    df['Y'] = pd.Categorical(df['Y'])
    return df

def repeate_lines_of_data(df, mult_obs):
    dfs = [df] * mult_obs
    df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    return df

def train_model(df):
    X = df[['X1', 'X2']]
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    model = sm.MNLogit(df['Y'].cat.codes, X)
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    result = model.fit()
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    param_x2 = result.params.iloc[2,0]
    p_value_x2 = result.pvalues.iloc[2,0]
    return (len(df), param_x2, p_value_x2)

res = []
for n_power in range(0,3):
    n_mult = 10**n_power
    print(n_mult)
    res.append(train_with_different_no_rows(n_mult))
res = pd.DataFrame(res)
res.columns = ['no_obs','x2_coeff','x2_p_value']
    
print(res)

Output:
   no_obs   x2_coeff     x2_p_value
0     100 -68.077325   2.067365e-02
1    1000 -68.077325   2.532576e-13
2   10000 -68.077325  1.879666e-118


statsmodels cannot do this. open issue https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8380 and related issues
